# Cannot access NSMutableDictionary from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to Objective C and I'm having a problem reading NSMutableDisctionary from another class. NSMutableDictionary itself is working fine in ViewController class, but when I try to read it in TestResults class i get empty dictionary. Where did I go wrong? Thanks!

**ViewController.h**

```
@property NSMutableDictionary *storedAnswers;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize questionScrollView;
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [_storedAnswers setObject:@"aaa" forKey:@"bbb"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

**TestResults.h**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

ViewController *answers = [[ViewController alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@",answers.storedAnswers);
```

Comment: This is a dupe a thousand times over.

Answer (score 2):

You're accessing the dictionary just fine.  You're not accessing the correct ViewController instance though.  You need to get a reference to the view controller--not just instantiate another instance of the view controller.

Comment: Would you be able to give an example of code how to do this please?

Comment: Any tutorial any where will show you how to pass data from view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think that _storedAnswers would be anything other than nil?

Comment: more of a recrimination that an answer

Answer (score 0):

_storedAnswers is never initialized (that we can see here).  Add:

```
_storedAnswers = [NSMutableDictionary new];
```

before you start using it.

Comment: this could do the job, as it passes data to another class but then i have to add some more data to this dictionary and it wont happen...

Answer (score 0):

**ViewController.h**

```
@property NSMutableDictionary *storedAnswers;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize questionScrollView;
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _storedAnswers = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [_storedAnswers setObject:@"aaa" forKey:@"bbb"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    _storedAnswers = nil; // free memory if ARC is enable
}
```

Comment: this passes the data. but what about if i want to add more data to this dictionary outside this method in ViewController.m ?

Comment: ViewController *answer = [[ViewController alloc] init];  [answer.storedAnswer setObject:@"secondObject" forKey:@"secondKey"];

Comment: so i would you use this in a second class. what about adding some more data in a class where that dictionary originally is?

Comment: Domas, can you more explain?

Comment: Right.. Your given answer technically works. It's a method that creates NSMutableDictionary and adds some data in it. That's fine.  But then later in a same class I have more methods where I want to put more data in to the same dictionary. And in the end, i want to read all that data in another class.. hope you understood me

Comment: if you want read data from dictionary use this: [_answerStored ObjectForKey:@"secondKey"]; this return value of key; and if you want get all keys or value you can use [_storedAnswer allKeys] or [_storedAnswer allValues]; // sorry for my bad english

Comment: ok, but i want to insert more data, not read

Comment: [_storedAnswers setObject:@"bbb" forKey:@"Key1"];       [_storedAnswers setObject:@"bbb" forKey:@"Key2"];      [_storedAnswers setObject:@"bbb" forKey:@"Key3"]; and more ?         what is this?

Comment: but if i use this line of code in different methods that doesn't work and this is a problem..

Comment: no, the data is just not added.. i guess i need to read some tutorials..